# Setting width of string or adding string to label

Tags: c++, string

I need to set width of string for window form's labels. As I was searching I haven't found any string function to set width. Also I tryed to do it with ostringstream but it seems to do not work :(

```
            ostringstream oss;
            oos << "HI ";
            string str = oos.str();
            labek->Text += str;
```

Comment: what do you mean? label size (pixels) or string size (chars)?

Comment: If you're going to use `ostringstream` check out the [IO Manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that. Chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    wostringstream oss;
    oss.width(5); //<--- set desired width in characters
    oss.fill(' '); //<-- what fill character you want to use to complete to width. 
    oss << "HI ";
    wstring str = oss.str();
    //cout<<"'"<<str<<"'"<<endl;
    //now you should do: label->Text = str.c_str(); but, alas, I doesn't have this label...

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

This worked for me. I added, to a new form, label called `label1` and a button called `button1`.

When I press the button the label is changed.

Add these includes:

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
```

Here is the button click function:

```
   private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        std::wostringstream oss;
        oss.width(15); //<--- set desired width in characters
        oss.fill('*'); //<-- what fill character you want to use to complete to width. 
        oss << "HI";
        std::wstring str = oss.str();
        label1->Text = msclr::interop::marshal_as<String^>(str);
    }
```

Comment: Well I understand ostringstream width atributte but the problem is I need to add it label (label->Text=str) and I can't use cout :s Ty for reply anyway!

Comment: Well I try to do that but I get error function system::windows::forms::label::text::set cannot be called with std::string

Comment: Now the error is that label text set cannot be called with const char*

Comment: which label do you use? MFC? maybe you need to use wide char string?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, im just adding it with toolbox and i created project with clr

Comment: text set cannot be called with argument wstring :(

Comment: Now function cannot be called with argument wchar_t*

Comment: See my edit at the end of the answer. it worked for me.